# How to convert BOOL to JSON with NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

How do I add a `BOOL` to `NSMutableDictionary` so that I get `true` when serialized as JSON?

I cannot use `NSValue`, which is a valid object in the dictionary, but for `NSJSONSerialization`, `NSValue` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSNumber`:

```
@{ 
   @"foo": @YES
}
```